# регулярное выражение для самых вложенных скобок

Tags: регулярные-выражения

какое регулярное выражение подойдет для поиска самых вложенных скобок, например для строки  2 * ((4 + 8) / (5 + 6 * (2+3))) находилось бы совпадение (2+3)

Comment: а какая ваша конечная задача? Вычислить выражение? Почему именно регулярное выражение (можно использовать например стек)?

Comment: да, конечная задача вычислить выражение, первые, что пришло в голову это регулярки

Comment: @pavel действительно регулярки не самое удачное решение, попробую со стеком решить

Answer (score 0):

Именно самое вложенное - маловероятно. Но есть регулярка, которая может найти все выраженя, которые уже можно вычислять, т.е. `(4 + 8)` и `(2+3)`.

Это `\([^()]+\)` - Скобка + что угодно кроме скобок + скобка